# Shopify GraphQL Query to retrieve UTM Parameters from Orders

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I'm quite new to GraphQL syntax so would love to see why I am getting null back as my result.

What I am trying to is query orders in a store and retrieve back the UTM Params associated with that order.

This is the query:

```
query {
  orders(first:10) {
    edges {
      node {
        customerJourney {
          moments {
            ... on CustomerVisit {
              utmParameters {
                source
                campaign
                content
                medium
                term
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "orders": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "customerJourney": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 42,
      "actualQueryCost": 22,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000,
        "currentlyAvailable": 978,
        "restoreRate": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems all the customerJourney's are returning null. Is there something wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1):

Shopify will only show data on orders that are less than 60 days old. As you have stated "first: 10" you're asking for the first 10 orders on that store which are likely over 60 days old. Try getting the last 10 orders using the reverse boolean.

```html
query {
  orders(first: 10, reverse:true) {
    edges {
      node {
        customerJourney {
          moments {
            ... on CustomerVisit {
              utmParameters {
                source
                campaign
                content
                medium
                term
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```